# Is there any way to get the text which is not present in any tag? or is there any way to get the locator? Or am I taking the wrong element?

Tags: python, selenium, text, automation, assertion

DOM from where I need to get text which is underlined:

[image: DOM from where I need to get text which is underlined.]

I'm getting following error:

> "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

My code:

```py
#This my locator in page class 
success_msg_css = "div.alert.alert-success.alert-dismissable"

#This is the method defined
def AddCustomerSuccess(self):
    self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.success_msg_css)

#over here I am calling the function and trying to assert.
success_msg = self.ac.AddCustomerSuccess().text()
print("there is success msg", success_msg)

if success_msg == "The new customer has been added successfully.":
    assert True
else:
    assert False

self.logger.info("************************Test Add customer passed*************************")
```

How to get text from tag?

Comment: When the error occurred, did the customer been added successfully? Or did the success message is showing?  ```NoneType``` means you get ```None``` instead of the desired the web element object.  My guess here is because the ```success_msg_css``` doesn't exists on the page itself.

Comment: Yes, the customer has been added successfully, every time.  And the message is visible on the top of the page with close button. I even tried to close it by clicking on it but of no use.

Comment: @Frederickcjo I think error is due to as it is not under any tag although i have tried to get inner text, get attribute, get text and all others methods with which i could get it but fail. If anybody knows it please let me know.